# Как добавить значение в бд Django?

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, django

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить значение в поле таблицы базы данных в Django?
Расскажу чуть подробнее, в стандартную таблицу авторизации `auth_user` я добавил колонку `money`. Теперь я хочу,что бы после нажатия кнопки у авторизиронного юзера добавилось значение 10 в колонке `money`.
Честно говоря гуглил и не нашел ответ. Решил уже сюда написать!

Comment: Напишите свой Python код с SQL запросом.

Answer (score 0):

В стандартную таблицу авторизации auth_user ничего добавлять не надо. Создайте новую таблицу связав её со стандартной 1:1 и там добавляйте сколько угодно полей.

Comment: а как это сделать? я просто новичок в джанго